# Calculate the number of nodes on either side of an edge in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

A tree here means an acyclic undirected graph with **n** nodes and **n-1** edges. For each edge in the tree, calculate the number of nodes on either side of it. If on removing the edge, you get two trees having **a** and **b** number of nodes, then I want to find those values **a** and **b** for all edges in the tree (ideally in O(n) time).

Intuitively I feel a multisource BFS starting from all the "leaf" nodes would yield an answer, but I'm not able to translate it into code.

For extra credit, provide an algorithm that works in any general graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run a depth-first search (or a breadth-first search if you like it more) from any node.
That node will be called the root node, and all edges will be traversed only in the direction from the root node.

For each node, we calculate the number of nodes in its rooted subtree.
When a node is visited for the first time, we set this number to 1.
When the subtree of a child is fully visited, we add the size of its subtree to the parent.

After this, we know the number of nodes on one side of each edge.
The number on the other side is just the total minus the number we found.

*(The extra credit version of your question involves finding bridges in the graph on top of this as a non-trivial part, and thus deserves to be asked as a separate question if you are really interested.)*

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2    3
 / \  | \
5   6 7  8
```

If we cut the edge between node 1 and 2, The tree will surely split into two tree because there is only one unique edge between two nodes according to tree property:

```
1
 \
  3
  | \
  7  8
```

and

```
  2
 / \
5   6
```

So, now `a` is the number of nodes rooted at `1` and `b` is number of nodes rooted at `2`.

```
> Run one DFS considering any node as root.

> During DFS, for each node x, calculate nodes[x] and parent[x] where
       nodes [x] = k means number of nodes of sub-tree rooted at x is k
       parent[x] = y means y is parent of x.

> For any edge between node x and y where parent[x] = y:
            a := nodes[root] - nodes[x]
            b := nodes[x]
```

Time and space complexity both `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `n=b-a+1`. Due to this, you don't need to count both sides of the edge. This greatly simplifies things. A normal recursion over the nodes starting from the root is enough. Since your tree is undirected you don't really have a "root", just pick one of the leaves.

What you want to do is to "go down" the tree until you reach the bottom. Then you count backwards from there. The leaf returns 1, and each recursive step sums the return values for each edge and then increment by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java code. Function countEdges() takes in the adjacency list of the tree as an argument also current node and the parent node of the current node(here parent node means that current node was introduced by parent node in this DFS).

Here edge[][] stores the number of nodes on one side of the edge[i][j], obviously the number of nodes on the other side will be equal to (total nodes -  edge[i][j]).

```
int edge[][];  
int countEdges(ArrayList<Integer> adj[], int cur, int par) {
    // If current nodes is leaf node and is not the node provided by the calling function then return 1 
    if(adj[cur].size() == 1 && par != 0) return 1;
    int count = 1;
    // count the number of nodes recursively for each neighbor of current node.
    for(int neighbor: adj[cur]) {
        if(neighbor == par) continue;
        count += countEdges(adj, neighbor, cur);    
    }
    // while returning from recursion assign the result obtained in the edge[][] matrix.
    return edge[par][cur] = count;
}
```

Since we are visiting each node only once in the DFS time complexity should be O(V).